# JavaScript/NodeJS Add to Caller Object of Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, constructor, this

So, I made a constructor function in Node.JS, and I'm having some problems.

```
function server(server) {
    this.channels = new Array
    var channels = server.channels.array(); // Gets array of Channel  Objects

    channels.forEach(function(selectedchannel){
       if (selectedchannel.constructor.name == "TextChannel") {
            channels.push(selectedchannel.name)          // <- Here
      }
   });
```

I want to add the names of all channels to the this.channels array,
channels.push would add to the channels-variable and this.channels.push would select the anonymous function that I passed to forEach.
How do i do this?
(I'm a noob, have mercy)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
function Server(server) {
    let channels = server.channels.array();

    this.channels = channels.map(selectedchannel => {
       if (selectedchannel.constructor.name === 'TextChannel') {
            return selectedchannel.name;
      }
    }).filter(data => !!data);
}
```

Constructor functions should begin with capital letters.
Calling constructors for array, function and other types are not necessary, but calling it without the parenthesis is wrong.
The array map function returns an new array and the filter will remove the empty/falsy values.